# How can I put each line I extract through Perl regex into an array?

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, multiline

After extracting, I want to put each IP Address I extracted & printed on the screen into an array. How can I do this? Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $url = 'http://www.game-monitor.com/';
my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
my $useragent = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $useragent->request($request);
my $result = $response->content;

@m = ($result =~ /\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\b/sg);
foreach (@m) {
    print "$_\n";
}
}
```

Comment: (not related to the question, but still worth mentioning) I believe you want: my @m = ....   this could save you some headache later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What do you mean? Your IPs already are in an array, `@m`, but if you want to put them in something else, one at a time, you can use `push @somethingelse, $_`

Also, you should always use strict; Add these lines to top of your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```